# Altbeacon not detecting if app was killed

Tags: android, ibeacon, altbeacon

I know there is a lot of questions the same my question but really I tried all of the answers but I don't know, it's not clear for me! can I detect beacon after kill the app using service or anything? can show me the steps of this? some times working every 5-7 min then didn't work after maybe 15 or 30 min.
 sorry for bad English

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:  YES**

> When properly configured, the Android Beacon Library guarantees your app can respond to beacon events, even if the user does not manually launch the app or even if the user kills the app.

Details and limitations are described in the online documentation, "Detecting Beacons After App is Killed" [here](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/resume-after-terminate.html).

Specific instructions are in the **Starting an App in the Background** section of [this page.](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html) The key is to add this code to a custom Application class and configure that in your manifest:

```
Region region = new Region("com.example.myapp.boostrapRegion", null, null, null);
regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, region);
```

Comment: I'm already using this code, and as i update my question i said i can detect the beacon after app kill but scan start every 5-7 min then after maybe 15-30 min didn't detect any more

Comment: and where can i but the code in this link : http://www.davidgyoungtech.com/2017/08/07/beacon-detection-with-android-8                              as i read this code will make scan period faster after app killed ? and i want to ask if i can make it every 1 sec ,

Comment: all what i need to create application to detecte the beacon every secound then call API if enter and exit . just , can i do this and must work every second because i want to calculate the time between enter and exit and must work after app killed or just leave the mobile long time

Comment: Lots of distinct questions in the comments here.  You really need to stick to one question per StackOverflow posting to meet the format of this site -- stay focussed.  I suggest you break up your questions into a list, prioritize them, then post one at a time starting with the most important.  Perhaps, "Why do beacon detections stop after 15-30 min?"  You would post a new question that (a) shows your code (b) describes in detail your test setup and (c) describes what is unexpected and how you witness it.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: the new question was posted